# How to convert Binary images and display it in Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void rptProducts1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{                      
    Image img = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgProduct");
    if (img != null)
    {
        var Binary = img.ImageUrl;
        img.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + (lstProductModel.Select(v => v.Picture = "" + Convert.ToBase64String(v.PictureBinary)));
    }
}
```

The error is when i try to convert binary image format to base64string the image is not displayed.
So please help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read/retrieve the image stored in binary form from the sql server database and show in Repeater data control

```
bytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[i]["BookPic"];
                        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                        Image img = (Image)rptBooks.Controls[i].FindControl("ImgBookPic");
                        img.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

Click  http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2014/04/upload-and-save-image-in-binary-format.html

Answer (score 1):

Asp code:

```
 <asp:Image ID="image" runat="server" />
```

C# Code to retrieve binary data from database:

```
byte[] picbyte = (byte[])reader["image"];
ByteArrayToImagebyMemoryStream(picbyte);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(picbyte, 0, picbyte.Length);
image.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

using this method :

```
 public static Image ByteArrayToImagebyMemoryStream(byte[] imageByte)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return image;
        }
```